# keycharmp file error in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I have used following code to check if Android's hardware back buttoon is clicked in PhoneGap
But it gives me error `Can't open keycharmap file`

so I am unable to check if Android's back button is clicked or not?

```
  document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
  function onBackKeyDown() 
  {
     alert("Back");
  }
```